# Apply re.sub to list If dictionary value == x

Tags: python

edit 9 Dec 2020:
I have been asked to clarify the question.
The best clarification I can offer is that ShadowRanger's code:

```py
    for k, cnt in stock.items(): 
        stage = [s for s in stage if s.count(k) <= cnt]
```

...does what I was trying to achieve plus much more (eliminating other now redundant code).

I have a limited alphabet "stock" (think Scrabble tiles) and need to eliminate words in array "stage" that cannot be built from stock.

My Perl example handles the case where I have a "stock" of one of a character and a "stage" containing words that require two or more of that character, and flagged those words for deletion (more precisely for exclusion from a later grep to the final array).

- stock=1, required>1 is the most common case.
- stock=2, required>2 is less common, and was ignored by my filter
- stock=0 was handled by a separate filter.

ShadowRanger's code covers all cases of stock=n, required>n ...perfect.

Sorry I screwed up my explanations: will try harder next time.

Chris

---

Python newbie trying to do something that worked in Perl but can’t find the Pythonic equivalent.

I have a dictionary char: available count of char

```
stock = {'p': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1}
```

and a list:

```
stage = ['pap', 'pal', 'pat', 'pop', 'pot', 'tap', 'tat', 'top']
```

What I want to do is eliminate any strings in *stage* that cannot be constructed from *stock*. This is one of several steps to eliminate “unworthy” candidates from *stage*. Current plan is to substitute unworthy strings with ‘?’. Strings containing ‘?’ will be filtered out when *stage* is sent to its final destination.
Goal -- in *stage*:
'pap' -> '?'
'pop' -> '?'  ...etc

Perl:
WORKS

```
$badchar = '?';
foreach my $key (keys %stock){
   if ($stock{$key} == 1){
      grep (s/^.*$key.*$key/$badchar/, @stage);
   }
}
```

Python:
DOES NOT WORK

```
    for k in stock:
      if stock[k] == 1:
        pattern = 'r".*' + k + '.*' + k + '.*"'
        replacement = '?'
        for w in stage:
          w = re.sub(pattern, replacement, w)
```

I’ve tried a dozen other ways in Python …this is the first that doesn’t raise an error, but it doesn’t substitute either!

The other stage pruning steps work, this one doesn’t! In my (simple) test-case, I’m down from a quarter-million entries in stage to around 210 before trying this step. This pruning step might take stage down to 190 entries, so I could simply abandon the quest, but it ought to be do-able in Python. This is part of a few-seconds setup-phase of a process that can happily take an hour or more to complete, so:
*Works-fast* is not important; *Works* is good; *Works AND elegant* is best.

EDIT: in response to my "illustrative" data being inadequate.

Here is a real case:
The illustrative 'P' example doesn't work in this case (2 in stock), but consider `'TAT', 'TET', 'TIT', 'TOT'` (`'TUT'` already eliminated from stage).

```
stock = {'C': 1, 'A': 3, 'P': 2, 'O': 1, 'T': 2, 'H': 1, 'E': 2, 'I': 1, 'N': 1, 'M': 1, 'S': 1}
```

And if you have the patience for a long stage, here it is in the same real case as above:

```
stage = ['ACE', 'ACT', 'AHA', 'AHS', 'AIA', 'AIM', 'AIN', 'AIS', 'AIT', 'AMI', 'AMP', 'ANA', 'ANE', 'ANI', 'ANN', 'APE', 'APT', 'ASH', 'ASP', 'ASS', 'ATE', 'ATS', 'CAM', 'CAN', 'CAT', 'CEE', 'CEP', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHI', 'CIT', 'CON', 'COO', 'COP', 'COS', 'COT', 'EAN', 'EAS', 'EAT', 'EEN', 'EHS', 'EME', 'EMS', 'ENA', 'ENE', 'ENS', 'EON', 'ESS', 'EST', 'ETA', 'ETH', 'HAE', 'HAH', 'HAN', 'HAP', 'HAS', 'HAT', 'HEM', 'HEN', 'HEP', 'HES', 'HET', 'HIC', 'HIE', 'HIM', 'HIN', 'HIP', 'HIS', 'HIT', 'HOA', 'HOC', 'HOE', 'HOH', 'HOI', 'HON', 'HOO', 'HOP', 'HOS', 'HOT', 'ICE', 'ICH', 'IMP', 'INA', 'INN', 'INS', 'ION', 'IOS', 'ISH', 'ISM', 'ITA', 'ITS', 'MAA', 'MAC', 'MAE', 'MAM', 'MAN', 'MAO', 'MAP', 'MAT', 'MEN', 'MET', 'MHO', 'MIA', 'MIM', 'MIS', 'MNA', 'MOA', 'MOE', 'MOM', 'MON', 'MOO', 'MOP', 'MOT', 'NAE', 'NAH', 'NAM', 'NAN', 'NAP', 'NAS', 'NAT', 'NEE', 'NEO', 'NEP', 'NET', 'NIM', 'NIP', 'NIS', 'NIT', 'NOH', 'NON', 'NOS', 'NOT', 'NTH', 'OAT', 'OCA', 'OCH', 'OES', 'OHM', 'OHO', 'OHS', 'OIS', 'OMS', 'ONE', 'OOH', 'OOM', 'OON', 'OOS', 'OPE', 'OPS', 'PAH', 'PAM', 'PAN', 'PAP', 'PAS', 'PAT', 'PEA', 'PEC', 'PEE', 'PEI', 'PEP', 'PET', 'PHI', 'PHO', 'PIA', 'PIC', 'PIE', 'PIN', 'PIP', 'PIS', 'PIT', 'POA', 'POE', 'POH', 'POI', 'POM', 'PON', 'POO', 'POP', 'POS', 'POT', 'PSI', 'SAC', 'SAE', 'SAI', 'SAM', 'SAN', 'SAP', 'SAT', 'SEA', 'SEC', 'SEE', 'SEI', 'SEN', 'SET', 'SHE', 'SHS', 'SIC', 'SIM', 'SIN', 'SIP', 'SIS', 'SIT', 'SOC', 'SOH', 'SON', 'SOP', 'SOS', 'SOT', 'SPA', 'STS', 'TAE', 'TAI', 'TAM', 'TAN', 'TAO', 'TAP', 'TAS', 'TAT', 'TEA', 'TEC', 'TEE', 'TEN', 'TET', 'THO', 'TIC', 'TIM', 'TIN', 'TIP', 'TIS', 'TIT', 'TOC', 'TOE', 'TOM', 'TON', 'TOO', 'TOP', 'TOT']
```

Hmmm, apparently still not clear -- having another go.

Consider the words starting 'T'

'TUT' has already been eliminated by an earlier filter (zero 'U' in stock).

'TAT', 'TET', 'TIT', TOT' must be eliminated - each requires 2*'T' and there is only 1*'T' in stock.

Similarly 'INN' (only 1*'N' in stock), 'OON' ...and probably others I didn't notice

Comment: Could you add the output?

Comment: What means "constructed from stock"? stock doesn't contain vowels so every item in stage should be removed if stock would define the maximum number of each letter allowed.

Comment: Please refrain from using curly quotes in program code.

Comment: @Dani Mesaejo: output == EXACTLY input. Real case is 210 strings so I won't post here, but really -- output = input, letter for letter, list==list, not a '?' anywhere.

Comment: Change your pattern to `pattern = fr".*{k}.*{k}.*"`

Comment: The expected output would apparently be the empty set, since none of the words in your example contain only letters from `stock`. What we would like to see, then, is an actually useful example where some strings are kept in the output, and it's clear exactly why those examples are kept.

Comment: Yeah.  After submitting an answer, I'm now confused about what you want. I would suggest that you present sample input and output, with all the interesting cases accounted for, like the use of double letters in a word that should be matched and double letters in a word that shouldn't be matched if that is possible (that is, if a single use of a character would match, but two uses should fail). The fact that none of your candidates seem to be matchable is particularly unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still not clear if the prose or the code is correct, and what the expected result for these inputs should be. As you can see, you have received three wildly different interpretations (of which one is deleted); can you address their assumptions in another update, and let us know if any of them understood you correctly?

Comment: @Steve (sorry trepleee can only at 1) please see edit to OP. I can't provide you genuine output because I can't generate it! But consider only words beginning 'T'' -- 'TUT' is already eliminated (no 'U' in stock), 'TAT', 'TET', 'TIT', 'TOT' should be eliminated (only one 'T' in stock.

Comment: So is my assumption correct that `stock` tells us how many of each letter we can use? Or is @ShadowRanger correct that we should replace anything from `stock` which has the count 1 and which occurs twice in the input string, like your Perl code does?

Comment: So what is the correct output here for your new data???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution that continues to use regex (see below for better approach)

```
pattern = 'r".*' + k + '.*' + k + '.*"'
```

isn't doing what you want. You seem to want it to be a raw string literal, but you're just making a regular string beginning with `r"` and ending with `"`. If you want to make an actual pattern that is raw, you could do something like:

```
pattern = fr'.*{k}.*{k}.*'  # Change k to re.escape(k) in each case if it might contain regex specials
```

You also need to replace the values in `stage`; Perl has mutable strings, Python doesn't, so you can't apply the substitution without storing the result (a brand new string), in this case by replacing the original string with the result. A simple solution would be a listcomp to replace `stage` in bulk, getting the final code:

```
import re
stock = {'p': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1}
stage = ['pap', 'pal', 'pat', 'pop', 'pot', 'tap', 'tat', 'top']
for k in stock:
    if stock[k] == 1:
        pattern = fr'.*{k}.*{k}.*'
        replacement = '?'
        stage = [re.sub(pattern, replacement, w) for w in stage]  # List comp to replace
        print(stage)
```

### Solution without regex

If the goal is as simple as "Remove all strings where a `stock` value mapped to `1` occurs two or more times in the string", you can do that without regular expressions (and without replacing to make new strings, just filtering the existing strings out):

```
for k, cnt in stock.items(): # Avoid lookup of stock[k] by getting paired key/value
    if cnt == 1:
        # Throws away "bad" strings instead of replacing them with '?':
        stage = [s for s in stage if s.count(k) < 2]

        # If you really want the '?' strings preserved:
        stage = [s if s.count(k) < 2 else '?' for s in stage]
```

removing the "bad" strings all at once without a regex in sight. This is a pretty common case when converting Perl to Python; Perl uses regex for everything aside from a couple really simple cases (`chomp`, `chop`, `substr`), while Python provides methods that reduce the need for regular expressions in the first place.

It looks like you may have intended to remove anything that had the `stock` character more than its associated count times (so for `stock[k] == 1`, you'd eliminate strings with `k` repeated two or more times, for `stock[k] == 2`, three or more times, etc.), so making it apply that filter gets you:

```
for k, cnt in stock.items(): # Avoid lookup of stock[k] by getting paired key/value
    # Throws away "bad" strings instead of replacing them with '?':
    stage = [s for s in stage if s.count(k) <= cnt]

    # If you really want the '?' strings preserved:
    stage = [s if s.count(k) <= cnt else '?' for s in stage]
```

where the `s.count(k) <= cnt` is using the `dict`'s `cnt` as the repetition limit.

Comment: What is significant about `cnt == 1`?

Comment: @Steve: It matches the behavior of the original Perl code and the attempted Python code, both of which ignored elements in `stock` that didn't have a value of `1` (they weren't used for replacements at all). I don't know *why* it did this, so I'm just following the behavior (the description of the intent is too vague, and frankly contradicts the code, so it's essentially impossible to answer; porting the code as is is answerable).

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well then maybe it would have been better to just show the Perl code.  I'm not a Perl programmer, so I tried to get what you needed from the description, although I can figure the Perl out.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, it's not great. In the edited question, there is an implication that those values have meaning, and really it should be filtering out anything where the character in question appears too many times (not just `if cnt == 1`, reject repetition of `2` or more); my last edit handles that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, Yes, YES!  My simple Perl example kills doubles where I have only one in stock. Killing ALL demanding more than available in stock would be fabulous (but silly in the length=3 simple illustrative example given)..

Comment: @ShadowRanger:-- that last looks PERFECT (and throws away one of my earlier filters that removed words that included letters not in stock). Trying it now, but it is late here, so feedback could be delayed (typos, sleep, etc)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: perfect! Needed a small tweak to my stock dictionary (original did not include zero-counts), but works very well.  Thank you.

Comment: @chrisM: You're welcome. Please remember to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it given it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt seems rather too complex. How about this?

```py
for candidate in stage:
  k = candidate
  for char in stock:
    k = k.replace(char, '', stock[char])
  if k == '':
    print('keep', candidate)
```

Here's a somewhat denser version;

```py
from functools import reduce

keep = [k for k in stage
        if reduce(lambda s, t: s.replace(t[0], '', t[1]),
                  stock.items(), k) == '']
```

Comment: I don't think this preserves the intended behavior; the OP seems to want to eliminate them only when the character occurs twice. It could be made to work with a simple `count` call, assuming all the replacements are that simple, but not with just `replace`.

Comment: I went with their prose description: the Perl code doesn't seem to reflect what they are describing anyway.  I have assumed that "available count of char" means `stock` indicates how many we can use of each character when extracting a word. Given `stock = {'p': 2, 'a': 1, 'q': 42, 't': 2}` this will extract `pap` (consuming 2 `p` and one `a`) and `pat` (consuming one each of `p`, `a`, and `t`).

Comment: ... But thanks for reminding me why we shouldn't attempt to answer unclear questions.

Comment: Yeah, the prose description doesn't seem to be accurate (and it's kind of vague) if we take them at their word that the Perl code works, so I mostly ignored it, in favor of following the working code. At least the Perl code clearly does a thing that can be reproduced in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed PERL in a long time, but I figured out how to get the code given in this question, along with the sample data, to spit out a result.  As I suspected, most of the `stage` ends up in the output untouched, with just entries that have two instances of one of the letters in `stock` with a value of `1` replaced with '?'.  I then did enough massaging of the output to make it easy to compare to the Python output.

Here's how I printed the Perl output:

```
print("[");
foreach $stage (@stage) {
  print "'$stage', ";
}
print("]\n")
```

Then I converted the Perl to Python, to see if I'd get the same result.
Here's the Python code that is my best attempt to translate the Perl code unchanged:

```
badchar = '?'
for key, val in stock.items():
    if val == 1:
        for i in range(len(stage)):
            stage[i] = re.sub(r'^.*{0}.*{0}'.format(key), '?', stage[i])
print(stage)
```

Below are the Perl and then Python output. They are basically the same.  So unless I screwed up the Perl code in how I fed it input or printed the result (I didn't change the provided code at all), this should verify the Python code.

Here's the Perl output:

```
['ACE', 'ACT', 'AHA', 'AHS', 'AIA', 'AIM', 'AIN', 'AIS', 'AIT', 'AMI', 'AMP', 'ANA', 'ANE', 'ANI', '?', 'APE', 'APT', 'ASH', 'ASP', '?', 'ATE', 'ATS', 'CAM', 'CAN', 'CAT', 'CEE', 'CEP', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHI', 'CIT', 'CON', '?', 'COP', 'COS', 'COT', 'EAN', 'EAS', 'EAT', 'EEN', 'EHS', 'EME', 'EMS', 'ENA', 'ENE', 'ENS', 'EON', '?', 'EST', 'ETA', 'ETH', 'HAE', '?', 'HAN', 'HAP', 'HAS', 'HAT', 'HEM', 'HEN', 'HEP', 'HES', 'HET', 'HIC', 'HIE', 'HIM', 'HIN', 'HIP', 'HIS', 'HIT', 'HOA', 'HOC', 'HOE', '?', 'HOI', 'HON', '?', 'HOP', 'HOS', 'HOT', 'ICE', 'ICH', 'IMP', 'INA', '?', 'INS', 'ION', 'IOS', 'ISH', 'ISM', 'ITA', 'ITS', 'MAA', 'MAC', 'MAE', '?', 'MAN', 'MAO', 'MAP', 'MAT', 'MEN', 'MET', 'MHO', 'MIA', '?', 'MIS', 'MNA', 'MOA', 'MOE', '?', 'MON', '?', 'MOP', 'MOT', 'NAE', 'NAH', 'NAM', '?', 'NAP', 'NAS', 'NAT', 'NEE', 'NEO', 'NEP', 'NET', 'NIM', 'NIP', 'NIS', 'NIT', 'NOH', '?', 'NOS', 'NOT', 'NTH', 'OAT', 'OCA', 'OCH', 'OES', 'OHM', '?', 'OHS', 'OIS', 'OMS', 'ONE', '?H', '?M', '?N', '?S', 'OPE', 'OPS', 'PAH', 'PAM', 'PAN', 'PAP', 'PAS', 'PAT', 'PEA', 'PEC', 'PEE', 'PEI', 'PEP', 'PET', 'PHI', 'PHO', 'PIA', 'PIC', 'PIE', 'PIN', 'PIP', 'PIS', 'PIT', 'POA', 'POE', 'POH', 'POI', 'POM', 'PON', '?', 'POP', 'POS', 'POT', 'PSI', 'SAC', 'SAE', 'SAI', 'SAM', 'SAN', 'SAP', 'SAT', 'SEA', 'SEC', 'SEE', 'SEI', 'SEN', 'SET', 'SHE', '?', 'SIC', 'SIM', 'SIN', 'SIP', '?', 'SIT', 'SOC', 'SOH', 'SON', 'SOP', '?', 'SOT', 'SPA', '?', 'TAE', 'TAI', 'TAM', 'TAN', 'TAO', 'TAP', 'TAS', 'TAT', 'TEA', 'TEC', 'TEE', 'TEN', 'TET', 'THO', 'TIC', 'TIM', 'TIN', 'TIP', 'TIS', 'TIT', 'TOC', 'TOE', 'TOM', 'TON', '?', 'TOP', 'TOT']
```

and the Python output:

```
['ACE', 'ACT', 'AHA', 'AHS', 'AIA', 'AIM', 'AIN', 'AIS', 'AIT', 'AMI', 'AMP', 'ANA', 'ANE', 'ANI', '?', 'APE', 'APT', 'ASH', 'ASP', '?', 'ATE', 'ATS', 'CAM', 'CAN', 'CAT', 'CEE', 'CEP', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHI', 'CIT', 'CON', '?', 'COP', 'COS', 'COT', 'EAN', 'EAS', 'EAT', 'EEN', 'EHS', 'EME', 'EMS', 'ENA', 'ENE', 'ENS', 'EON', '?', 'EST', 'ETA', 'ETH', 'HAE', '?', 'HAN', 'HAP', 'HAS', 'HAT', 'HEM', 'HEN', 'HEP', 'HES', 'HET', 'HIC', 'HIE', 'HIM', 'HIN', 'HIP', 'HIS', 'HIT', 'HOA', 'HOC', 'HOE', '?', 'HOI', 'HON', '?', 'HOP', 'HOS', 'HOT', 'ICE', 'ICH', 'IMP', 'INA', '?', 'INS', 'ION', 'IOS', 'ISH', 'ISM', 'ITA', 'ITS', 'MAA', 'MAC', 'MAE', '?', 'MAN', 'MAO', 'MAP', 'MAT', 'MEN', 'MET', 'MHO', 'MIA', '?', 'MIS', 'MNA', 'MOA', 'MOE', '?', 'MON', '?', 'MOP', 'MOT', 'NAE', 'NAH', 'NAM', '?', 'NAP', 'NAS', 'NAT', 'NEE', 'NEO', 'NEP', 'NET', 'NIM', 'NIP', 'NIS', 'NIT', 'NOH', '?', 'NOS', 'NOT', 'NTH', 'OAT', 'OCA', 'OCH', 'OES', 'OHM', '?', 'OHS', 'OIS', 'OMS', 'ONE', '?H', '?M', '?N', '?S', 'OPE', 'OPS', 'PAH', 'PAM', 'PAN', 'PAP', 'PAS', 'PAT', 'PEA', 'PEC', 'PEE', 'PEI', 'PEP', 'PET', 'PHI', 'PHO', 'PIA', 'PIC', 'PIE', 'PIN', 'PIP', 'PIS', 'PIT', 'POA', 'POE', 'POH', 'POI', 'POM', 'PON', '?', 'POP', 'POS', 'POT', 'PSI', 'SAC', 'SAE', 'SAI', 'SAM', 'SAN', 'SAP', 'SAT', 'SEA', 'SEC', 'SEE', 'SEI', 'SEN', 'SET', 'SHE', '?', 'SIC', 'SIM', 'SIN', 'SIP', '?', 'SIT', 'SOC', 'SOH', 'SON', 'SOP', '?', 'SOT', 'SPA', '?', 'TAE', 'TAI', 'TAM', 'TAN', 'TAO', 'TAP', 'TAS', 'TAT', 'TEA', 'TEC', 'TEE', 'TEN', 'TET', 'THO', 'TIC', 'TIM', 'TIN', 'TIP', 'TIS', 'TIT', 'TOC', 'TOE', 'TOM', 'TON', '?', 'TOP', 'TOT']
```

You just have to look for '?' entries.  They exist in the same places in both lists.  So unless I screwed up the Perl code in how I fed it input or printed the result, this should be the Python code you're looking for.

Comment: NOTE: I don't care about points here or about taking any credit for having the answer first.  It looks like other answers are similar to mine, and they came before mine.  I just wanted to go through the exercise of running the Perl to be sure we all knew what the right result was.  If others had done similarly, or had shown their result with the whole dataset, I probably wouldn't have written the Python version myself.  But I had to to be able to compare the output.  Once I did that, I wanted to show y'all the result.  Maybe others can run their code and see if they get the same result.